# Can't use more than 16 bits in Filter class

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I require more than 16 categories for collision, but unfortunately the Filter class's `categoryBits` is only a short which is only 16 bits. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx uses Bulletphysics which has a known limitation with the number of collision group filters you can create (a 16bits integer). This limitation is voluntary since the developers of Bullet consider that more groups are not necessary.

Collision groups are a mean of optimization: They prevent the bounding box checks altogether, and of course the event from firing. Without a group filter, you can still check for the collision through the event to make sure yourself if the objects are meant to collision or not.

The groups should only be used for objects which overlaps frequently but should not trigger a collision. for objects which almost never overlap, don't use groups, use a check in the event.

Now if you *really* need more groups for some reason, the best way is to create a new physic world.

Comment: Since the question is tagged as box2d I don't think he's using the bullet wrapper.

Comment: Right, the answer is probably correct for Box2D too since the philosophy behind a physic engine is the same.

Comment: Although I am not using the bullet wrapper as Xoppa mentioned, Guillaume  is correct when he mentions that groups are not required for all my collisions. I will use the `beginContact()` method to compare colliding objects rather than their bits.